# Partitioning in spark while reading from RDBMS via JDBC

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql, partitioning

I am running spark in cluster mode and reading data from RDBMS via JDBC.

As per Spark [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#jdbc-to-other-databases), these partitioning parameters describe how to partition the table when reading in parallel from multiple workers:

- `partitionColumn`
- `lowerBound`
- `upperBound`
- `numPartitions`

*These are optional parameters.*

What would happen if I don't specify these:

- Only 1 worker read the whole data?
- If it still reads parallelly, how does it partition data?

Comment: Do you have sample code to read records from RDBMS via jdbc?

Comment: @SurenderRaja you can check - https://gist.github.com/devender-yadav/5c4328918602b7910ba883e18b68fd87

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't specify either {`partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`, `numPartitions`} or {`predicates`} Spark will use a single executor and create a single non-empty partition. All data will be processed using a single transaction and reads will be neither distributed nor parallelized.

See also:

- [How to optimize partitioning when migrating data from JDBC source?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52603131/6910411)
- [How to improve performance for slow Spark jobs using DataFrame and JDBC connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32188295/6910411)

Comment: what about writing through JDBC, df.write.mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc("<other database url>", "<same table name>", <some DbProperties>)