# Spark read database rows in chunks?

Tags: apache-spark

I am querying a database using `spark.read.jdbc` method that is quite large and getting the following error:

`com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (15,913,800 > 4,194,304)`

which indicates the retrieved data is too large.
I don't have the option to alter the database settings and I need to be able to retrieve all of the data so I would like to read the data in chunks and have the result be a dataframe. How can I achieve this?

For example, in python I can query a database using pandas and read it in chunks [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html), you can find the `fetchsize` option that you may pass to the `spark.read.jdbc`...

Comment: Thought the general way was number of partitions, etc.

Comment: @thebluephantom I think that would be for specifying parallelism - not # of rows. Alex Ott answer looks correct

Comment: True, but in an abstract way it also achieves the same I think if I read the question. Anyway.

Comment: if the table was consistently the same size yes it would if I used a large enough parallelism. but if the table is growing in size then at some point I'd reach the same error. so using `fetchsize` for my use case is needed as my target table will continue to grow

Comment: @thebluephantom by default, there is no parallelization on read, until you specify `partitionColumn`, `lowerBound`, `upperBound`.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43150938/18627