# Achieve concurrency when saving to a partitioned parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

When writing a `dataframe` to  `parquet` using `partitionBy` :

```
df.write.partitionBy("col1","col2","col3").parquet(path)
```

It would be my expectation that each partition being written were done independently by a separate task and in parallel to the extent of the number of workers assigned to the current spark job.

However there is actually only one worker/task running at a time when writing to the parquet. That one worker is cycling through each of the partitions and writing out the `.parquet` files serially.  Why would this be the case - and is there a way to compel concurrency in this `spark.write.parquet` operation?

The following is *not* what I want to see (should be `700%+` ..)

[image]

From this other post  I also tried adding `repartition` in front

[Spark parquet partitioning : Large number of files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44808415/spark-parquet-partitioning-large-number-of-files)

```
df.repartition("col1","col2","col3").write.partitionBy("col1","col2","col3").parquet(path)
```

This unfortunately had no effect: still one worker only..

Note: I am running in `local` mode with `local[8]` and have seen *other* spark operations run with as many as eight concurrent workers and using up to 750% of the cpus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, writing the multiple output files from a single task is not parallelized, but assuming you have multiple tasks (multiple input splits) each one of those will get their own core on a worker.

The goal of writing out partitioned data isn't to parallelize your writing operation.  Spark is already doing that by simultaneously writing out multiple tasks at once.  The goal is just to optimize future read operations where you want only one partition of the saved data.

The logic to write partitions in Spark is designed to read all of the records from the previous stage only once when writing them out to their destination.  I believe part of the design choice is also to protect against the case where
a partition key has many many values.

**EDIT: Spark 2.x method**

In Spark 2.x, it sorts the records in each task by their partition keys, then it iterates through them writing to one file handle at a time.  I assume they are doing this to ensure they never open a huge number of file handles if there are a lot of distinct values in your partition keys.

For reference, here is the sorting:

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter.scala#L121

Scroll down a little and you will see it calling `write(iter.next())` looping through each row.

And here is the actual writing (one file/partition key at a time):

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/FileFormatWriter.scala#L121

There you can see it only holds one file handle open at a time.

**EDIT: Spark 1.x method**

What spark 1.x does is for a given task is loop through all the records, opening a new file handle whenever it encounters a new output partition it hasn't seen before for this task.  It then immediately writes the record to that file handle and goes onto the next one.  This means at any given time while processing a single task it can have up to N file handles open just for that one task where N is the maximum number of output partitions.  To make it clearer, here is some python psuedo-code to show the general idea:

```py
# To write out records in a single InputSplit/Task
handles = {}
for row in input_split:
    partition_path = determine_output_path(row, partition_keys)
    if partition_path not in handles:
        handles[partition_path] = open(partition_path, 'w')

    handles[partition_path].write(row)
```

There is a caveat to the above strategy for writing out records.  In spark 1.x the setting `spark.sql.sources.maxConcurrentWrites` put an upper limit on the mask file handles that could be open per task.  After that was reached, Spark would instead sort the data by the partition key, so it could iterate through the records writing out one file at a time.

Comment: I'm not getting this as a "strategy":  `hive` for example uses the partitions to drive concurrency both on read and write. These are distinct directories and afford no obstacle to parallel writing. I mean in the end - if this were going to be the case then I could write my own routine to parallelize the writing of each partition in a different worker via `mapPartitions`.

Comment: Even if they are distinct folders, there are still considerations about number of concurrent file handles, and max total write IO you can do.  You could use mapPartitions to parallelize writing of tasks manually in theory, but you could also just increase the number of executors or cores to achieve the same thing (assuming your job has enough tasks)

Comment: Updated with more specific info for Spark 2

Comment: This is nice research. Holding the question open a bit longer in hopes of someone dropping in a workaround.  afa # of workers: the OP mentions they are 8 but only one is being used.  I'm more than a little surprised that it would be considered acceptable to use a single thread for all this.

Comment: Nice research, but how does it explain CPU usage with more than one partition. Even in `local` mode, each worker thread should work independently of others, shouldn't it?

Comment: Only one worker is writing the parquet.  As mentioned in the OP the `local[8]` is working fine (700+%) for *other* spark tasks : so it is parquet writing that is the problem.  It makes no sense to serialize this work.

Comment: @javadba Do you see "Only one worker (...)  writing" (by monitoring task execution) or just see low CPU utilization? These are not the same things. And "In short, writing the multiple output files from a single task is not parallelized" doesn't explain why it would happen with multiple tasks.

Comment: Its not low cpu utiliation -it's 100% of *one* Cpu. For tens of minutes.

Comment: @javadba I doesn't really answer the question, does it? CPU activity pattern like this can be caused by many unrelated reasons.

Comment: If you think I can not distinguish between one process causing cpu usage and multiple ones adding up to 100% then suit yourself.